# Запуск обработчика события в заданном контексте

Tags: javascript

Есть один флажок

```
<input type ="radio" id ="roundThingy" onchange='setPetitionerTrue();'>
```

Требуется программно сделать его отмеченным и запустить обработчик `setPetitionerTrue()` от его имени.

```
var radioButton = document.getElementById('roundThingy');
radioButton.checked = true;
```

Флажок отмечается, но обработчик не запускается. Нужно запустить его вручную, но таким образом, чтобы `event.target` значился искомый флажок `id = roundThingy` чтобы функция правильно работала. Как это сделать, либо как реализовать этот момент по-другому?

Comment: в данном случае `onchange='setPetitionerTrue();'` event не передается в качестве параметра, а в некоторых браузерах может отсутствовать глобальный объект event

Comment: @Grundy То, что я делаю, это не совсем сайт, кроссбраузерная поддержка не в приоритете (пока). Мне нужно чтобы функция `setPetitionerTrue()` была "привязана" к `<input type='radio' id='roundthingy'>`. Может лучше написать аналогичную функцию, но чтобы она принимала в себя объект флажка в качестве аргумента?

Comment: чтобы она была _привязана_, достаточно просто внутри обращаться напрямую к этому radioButton

Comment: @Grundy функция `setPetitionerTrue()` не знает заранее, какой элемент его запускает, ориентируется на `event.target`. Один флажок это только для примера. На самом деле их, конечно, несколько.

Comment: Замени внутри функции использование `event.target` на `el`, где `el` - это параметр: `function setPetitionerTrue(el){...}`, и передавай его при вызове `onchange='setPetitionerTrue(this);'`, тогда можно будет просто вызывать функцию setPetitionerTrue передавая ей нужный элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно запустить триггер события на элементе, например, так:

```js
function setPetitionerTrue() {
  console.log('setPetitionerTrue');
}

var radioButton = document.getElementById('roundThingy');

var event = new Event('change');
radioButton.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<input type ="radio" id ="roundThingy" onchange='setPetitionerTrue();'>
```